# MariaDB & Galera, ¿Que pasa si se pierde un nodo del cluster?

Tags: mariadb, cluster

Estoy siguiendo este [tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-galera-cluster-on-ubuntu-1604/) para montar un cluster con MariaDB yy Galera.

Mi duda es, ¿Si por lo que sea (se apaga la máquina, se quita de la red, etc..) el nodo 1 es afectado, el resto de nodos siguen manteniendo la replicación de las bases de datos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comento los siguientes puntos sobre la implementación de MariaDB/MySQL/Percona con Galera para aclarar dudas:

- Cada nodo tiene una copia completa de toda la data.
- Se recomienda como mínimo en un cluster la disponibilidad de 3 nodos para evitar el [split brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing)). Siempre debe haber 50% + 1 de quorum. Por esto debe ser un número impar de nodos; 3, 5, 7, 9...
- Puede darse el caso de tener dos nodos formando el cluster, situación que no cumple el mínimo definido en el punto anterior, entonces deberás usar Galera Arbitrator para evitar el Split Brain siempre y cuando estés escribiendo en ambos nodos.
- En caso de que un nodo deja de funcionar, el cluster sigue trabajando, es transparente. Para que esto se cumpla deberás añadir un servicio como un (HAProxy, ProxySQL / Service Discovery) para descartar automáticamente el nodo afectado o donante y nuevo.
- Cada nodo se replica con la cantidad de nodos disponibles. Esto implica un aumento del ancho de banda consumido por la NIC, y un coste adicional en los Cores de la CPU para dedicar ha este proceso de replicación, dependiendo del alto trafico puede saturarse uno de estos dos recursos.
- Cuando se añade un nodo, uno de los que ya conforman el cluster pasa ha ser un donante, y no prestará servicio hasta haber transferido todos los datos al nuevo nodo y estar sincronizado con el cluster, hasta entonces ninguno de los dos estará disponible.